# sending Model attribute methods to client Sails Angular

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, sails.js, waterline

Is there a trick to send the Model attribute functions over Http gets ?

so assuming i have a model User :

```
 attributes: {
     last_name : "string" ,  
     first_name: "string",
  name : function()
     {
        return this.first_name + " " + this.last_name;
     }
  }
```

Controller :

```
User.findOne( { id : 1}).exec(function(err,user) {
   res.view("profile", {user:user}); 
});
```

and a view :

```
<div> 
  <h4> hi <%= user.name() %>
</div>
```

everything works perfectly.

however if I am loading the data through a client : 
Controller :

```
User.findOne( { id : 1}).exec(function(err,user) {
   res.json({user:user}); // or res.send({user: user});
});
```

and in Client (Angular):

```
$http.get("/controller/method/").then(function(data){
$scope.user = data;
});
```

the view cannot do that anymore as easy as it used to :

```
<div>
 <h4> hi {{ user.name() }} </h4>
</div>
```

Any ideas or workarounds ? I tried overwriting the toJSON method of the model but no luck. would appreciate any ideas here.

Answer (score 1):

```
 attributes: {
     last_name : "string" ,  
     first_name: "string",
  name : function()
     {
        return this.first_name + " " + this.last_name;
     }
  },
    toJSON : function(){
      var obj = this.toObject();
      obj.name = this.first_name + " " + this.last_name;
      return obj;
    }
```

Comment: ok sounded legit in the beginning but its not really working with me. I dont think this function is really being called, i added a console log statement inside got nothing on calling it. did you test it before ?

Comment: ok got around it, toJSON is an attribute function it has to be inside the attributes object. I also cant send functions

Comment: My example is on the attributes object? This method works, fully tested.